# Many to Many relationship AND conditions filtering in Django mysql

Tags: django, python-3.x, lambda, django-views

I have below table in mysql

[image]

Here is the model:

```
class cube(models.Model):
    pid = models.IntegerField()
    av = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sid = models.IntegerField()
    st = models.IntegerField()
```

What am trying to achieve is that I want to know the list of pid's which has

```
(sid=1,st>=5) and (sid=2,st>=7)
```

This should result two pids - 3214 and 3215 from my table as per screenshot.
pid 3213 doesn't satisfy the condition, so it is not being returned.

I was trying below approaches to achieve my requirement in View:

**View Code:**

```
testq=(cube.objects.filter((Q(sid='1') & Q(srt_gte="5")) & (Q(sid='2') & Q(srt_gte="7")))
```

Also trying with lambda this way  -

```
input = [{"sid":1,"st":5},{"sid":2,"st":7}]
queries = [Q(sid=i['sid'], st__gte=i['st']) for i in input]
sid_query = reduce(lambda x, y:  ________ , queries)
```

In above lambda, I tried using case statement like 
    (lambda x:
     1 if queries else
     0
    )

```
queryset=cube.objects.values_list('pid').filter(sid_query).annotate('pid')
```

This doesn't work :(

Tried some other way like below:

```
testq=cube.objects.filter(Q(sid__in=[1,2])& (Q(srt__gte=[5,7]))).annotate(c=Count('sid')).filter(c=2)
```

Looks like this is wrong.

Not able to figure out how can I get the result as per my requirement.

```
 List of pid's who has (sid=1,st>=5) and (sid=2,st>=7)
```

Below is the SQL equivalent for the requirement:

```
select b.pid
from cube b
group by b.pid
having sum(case when (b.sid = 1) and (b.srt >= 5) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 AND
       sum(case when (b.sid = 2) and (b.srt >= 7) then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need an OR condition rather than an AND, and your first query looks nearly correct. You can combine some of your criteria in your Q objects to make it a bit more readable.

```
testq = cube.objects.filter(Q(sid='1', st_gte="5") | Q(sid='2', st_gte="7"))
```

The AND condition doesn't work because a single record in your database can't have both `sid=1` AND `sid=2` at the same time (those are two separate records). You can then use `testq.values_list('pid', flat=True)` to get just the `pid` values.

Note that this would give you duplicates (you should get something like `[3214, 3214, 3215, 3215]`), so you either need to convert to a set:

```
testq = set(testq)  # note: this will evaluate your query
```

or call `.distinct()` on the resulting queryset.

```
testq = testq.distinct()  # testq is still a QuerySet object.
```

An alternative would be to drop down and just use the `raw` method, if you're certain that your SQL query returns the results you wish.

```
testq = cube.objects.raw(your_sql)
```

You can then inspect the testq or iterate over it pulling out the data you need. See the[docs for Performing raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries)

Hope that helps.

Comment: if I use '|' in the filter, It returns rows that gets satisfied either of the conditions.. So, I would loose the required sets, am trying to get pids which gets satisfied on for both the conditions as per my input set.. That is the reason, I used case statement in my sql query grouped by pid

Comment: @SathishPanduga Have you considered using .raw to just run your query?  I just updated my answer with an example and a link to those docs.

Comment: Hi Brad, Thanks for updating! If I use raw query, it would be difficult to use  filter for 20 conditions.. Tried using multiple case statements based on the input, but I feel that there is more efficient way of doing the same than several statements in sql query. I have requirement to use 20 filters to the table .. that the problem.